# Resource group on google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to know if a "Resource group" feature i.e. a logical container for a collection of resources that can be treated as one logical instance, which helps me to keep all the resource types like Virtual machine, Network interface, Public IP address,Storage account,Virtual network and gateway etc. for a particular resource under a single resource name; has been implemented on Google Cloud Platform. This feature has been implemented in Azure and AWS.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what service in Google Cloud Platform you are referring to? Please add more information, because currently it is not obvious from your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is now implemented on Google Cloud Platform. Take a look at [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/).

Deployment Manager allows you to create and manage groups of Google Cloud Platform resources, and store/define them them under one deployment name/resource.